# How to calculate capacitor to fix a brownout

Tags: power-supply, esp32, brownout

I have connected an ESP32 to a 3v3 voltage regulator as seen in the picture below.
Essentially: Unregulated voltage ----[4.7uF]---LDO---[4.7uF]--[0.1uF]--

[image: LDO3V3]

Then at the ESP32 at the VIN i have [10uF]--[0.1uF]---ESP3V3 [Where all the caps are connected between LDO and ground].
The LDO datasheet https://www.digikey.com/en/datasheets/diodes-incorporated/diodes-incorporated-ap7361c

After connecting it the **ESP during wifi boot detects a brownout** and constantly resets.
The brown out can be seen below. The duration is aprox 1ms
[image: time_of_drop]
And the voltage drop is around 1V
[image: v_drop]

At the **input side of regulator** this is the brownout [image][image]

- How do i calculate the capacitors needed to avoid the brownout.
- How would you go around this problem?

I think the problem is that the capacitors i used are simply too slow (have big internal resistance?) to provide the current needed fast enough.

Comment: What does the voltage look like at the **input** side of the regulator? Take some scope photos of that. Also please provide a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for the regulator.

Comment: Good comment! I've added the scope images.

Comment: And the link to the datasheet....?

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/en/datasheets/diodes-incorporated/diodes-incorporated-ap7361c It’s this one. I’m sure it’s fast enough di/dt. I’ve solved the problem thanks to you sir! I added 1000uF at the input of the regulator and everything is working perfectly. The circuit is powered even by a power mux to switch between battery and usb. How can I award you the answer and the kudos?

Comment: Big question: is the regulator pulling out of regulation because the input is drooping, or because it is current limiting itself?  If the former, increasing CIN should be enough.  Tell us the DC input voltage to the regulator, the regulator's minimum headroom, and the regulator output current during the sag.  There are two equations that will work for you.  One is an approximation based on a constant current discharge, and a more accurate one based on the total energy stored in a capacitor.

Comment: @AnalogKid good question. Turns out the 4.7uF at the CIN is not good enough for WiFi transients. I’ve added a bigger CIN = 1000uF and it works. The regulator itself can pulse up to 1.5 amps (or more) and has a steady state output of 1A. The headroom at 1 Amp is 0.32V (from my tests), but my steady state current peaks at 0.15A. I would like to know the approx based on charge

Comment: You can compute the reason using KVL with current and ESR of source impedance including ESR of cap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Total energy is measured in watt-seconds (Ws or W-s).  Your brownout is approx 4 ms (3.36 ms in one trace), and lets say the transient current is 500 mA.  The total energy you need to make up is (3.3 x 0.5 x 0.004) = 0.0066 w-s.  Not much.

Regulator output (3.3 V) plus headroom (0.32 V) = Vin(min) - 3.62 V.  Lets round that up to 4.0 V for margin.

Total energy (in w-s) in a capacitor is 1/2 C V^2.  During the transient, the input capacitor discharges from its nominal value to the minimum regulator input value.  If the nominal Vin is 5.0 V (for example), then removing 0.0066 w-s of energy from the capacitor discharges it from V1 to V2 (5.0 V to 4.0 V).

0.0066 = 1/2 x C x (5.0^2) - 1/2 x C x (4.0^2)

Moving the pieces around:

C (in farads) = (0.0066 x 2) / (25 - 16) = 1466 uF

Note:  This example has a lot of worst-case assumptions and margin.  It is for a complete blackout, where the input voltage source goes to 0 V for 4.0 ms.  A shorter transient period, higher input voltage, and lower transient current all work to reduce the size of the holdup capacitor.

In this example, the resulting capacitor size is relatively high because the allowed voltage drop is so small.  Increasing the nominal input voltage by only one volt decreases the capacitor size by over 50%.

Comment: AnalogKid, Nice rush reference btw.... Where did the values 25 and 16 come from in the above cap formula? C (in farads) = (0.0066 x 2) / (25 - 16) = 1466 uF

Comment: The energy sucked out of the cap during a brownout is the energy at full charge (5 V) minus the energy left in the cap at the minimum voltage needed to run the regulator (4 V).  25 and 16 are the squares of those voltage values, per the equation in para 3.